# Tensorflow: Slice a 3D tensor with list of indices along the second axis

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a placeholder tensor with shape: `[batch_size, sentence_length, word_dim]` and a list of indices with `shape=[batch_size, num_indices]`. Indices are on the second axes and are indices of words in the sentence. `Batch_size & sentence_length` are only known at runtime.

How do I extract a tensor with shape `[batch_size, len(indices), word_dim]`?

I was reading about `tensorflow.gather` but it seems like gather only slices along the first axes. Am I correct?

Edit: I managed to get it work with constant

```
def tile_repeat(n, repTime):
    '''
    create something like 111..122..2333..33 ..... n..nn 
    one particular number appears repTime consecutively.
    This is for flattening the indices.
    '''
    print n, repTime
    idx = tf.range(n)
    idx = tf.reshape(idx, [-1, 1])    # Convert to a n x 1 matrix.
    idx = tf.tile(idx, [1, int(repTime)])  # Create multiple columns, each column has one number repeats repTime 
    y = tf.reshape(idx, [-1])
    return y

def gather_along_second_axis(x, idx):
    ''' 
    x has shape: [batch_size, sentence_length, word_dim]
    idx has shape: [batch_size, num_indices]
    Basically, in each batch, get words from sentence having index specified in idx
    However, since tensorflow does not fully support indexing,
    gather only work for the first axis. We have to reshape the input data, gather then reshape again
    '''
    reshapedIdx = tf.reshape(idx, [-1]) # [batch_size*num_indices]
    idx_flattened = tile_repeat(tf.shape(x)[0], tf.shape(x)[1]) * tf.shape(x)[1] + reshapedIdx
    y = tf.gather(tf.reshape(x, [-1,int(tf.shape(x)[2])]),  # flatten input
                idx_flattened)
    y = tf.reshape(y, tf.shape(x))
    return y

x = tf.constant([
            [[1,2,3],[3,5,6]],
            [[7,8,9],[10,11,12]],
            [[13,14,15],[16,17,18]]
    ])
idx=tf.constant([[0,1],[1,0],[1,1]])

y = gather_along_second_axis(x, idx)
with tf.Session(''):
    print y.eval()
    print tf.Tensor.get_shape(y)
```

And the output is:

```
[[[ 1  2  3]
  [ 3  5  6]]
 [[10 11 12]
  [ 7  8  9]]
 [[16 17 18]
  [16 17 18]]]
```

shape: `(3, 2, 3)`

However, when inputs are placeholder it does not work return error:

```
idx = tf.tile(idx, [1, int(repTime)])  
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Tensor'
```

Python 2.7, tensorflow 0.12

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'd flatten the first two dimensions of the placeholder and compute the index in the flattened dimension. `tf.gather` will be fine once that's done.

Comment: Hi @AllenLavoie: Thank you. I also got that idea from here[https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/206]. However, I cannot make it work for placeholder input. Could you take a quick look at my edited question?

Comment: You can use `tf.shape` to get dimensions as an integer Tensor. This works even when static shape information is not available.

Comment: Thank you. I got another error:
idx = tf.tile(idx, [1, int(repTime)])
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Tensor'

And also I am not sure whether we can get tf.tile to work with runtime dimensions?

Comment: Yes, `tile` works fine with Tensor dimensions. If `repTime` is already an integer Tensor, you may just need to remove the `int` cast (that's trying to make it into a regular Python integer, which it can't do). You can cast it with `tf.cast` if necessary.

Comment: My bad. Thank you very much, removing the int cast makes it work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank to @AllenLavoie's comments, I could eventually come up with the solution:

```
def tile_repeat(n, repTime):
    '''
    create something like 111..122..2333..33 ..... n..nn 
    one particular number appears repTime consecutively.
    This is for flattening the indices.
    '''
    print n, repTime
    idx = tf.range(n)
    idx = tf.reshape(idx, [-1, 1])    # Convert to a n x 1 matrix.
    idx = tf.tile(idx, [1, repTime])  # Create multiple columns, each column has one number repeats repTime 
    y = tf.reshape(idx, [-1])
    return y

def gather_along_second_axis(x, idx):
    ''' 
    x has shape: [batch_size, sentence_length, word_dim]
    idx has shape: [batch_size, num_indices]
    Basically, in each batch, get words from sentence having index specified in idx
    However, since tensorflow does not fully support indexing,
    gather only work for the first axis. We have to reshape the input data, gather then reshape again
    '''
    reshapedIdx = tf.reshape(idx, [-1]) # [batch_size*num_indices]
    idx_flattened = tile_repeat(tf.shape(x)[0], tf.shape(x)[1]) * tf.shape(x)[1] + reshapedIdx
    y = tf.gather(tf.reshape(x, [-1,tf.shape(x)[2]]),  # flatten input
                idx_flattened)
    y = tf.reshape(y, tf.shape(x))
    return y

x = tf.constant([
            [[1,2,3],[3,5,6]],
            [[7,8,9],[10,11,12]],
            [[13,14,15],[16,17,18]]
    ])
idx=tf.constant([[0,1],[1,0],[1,1]])

y = gather_along_second_axis(x, idx)
with tf.Session(''):
    print y.eval()
    print tf.Tensor.get_shape(y)
```

Answer (score 0):

@Hoa Vu's answer was very helpful. The code works with the example `x` and `idx` which is `sentence_length == len(indices)`, but it gives an error when `sentence_length != len(indices)`.

I slightly changed the code and now it works when `sentence_length >= len(indices)`.

I tested with new `x` and `idx` on Python 3.x.

```
def tile_repeat(n, repTime):
    '''
    create something like 111..122..2333..33 ..... n..nn 
    one particular number appears repTime consecutively.
    This is for flattening the indices.
    '''
    idx = tf.range(n)
    idx = tf.reshape(idx, [-1, 1])    # Convert to a n x 1 matrix.
    idx = tf.tile(idx, [1, repTime])  # Create multiple columns, each column has one number repeats repTime 
    y = tf.reshape(idx, [-1])
    return y


def gather_along_second_axis(x, idx):
    ''' 
    x has shape: [batch_size, sentence_length, word_dim]
    idx has shape: [batch_size, num_indices]
    Basically, in each batch, get words from sentence having index specified in idx
    However, since tensorflow does not fully support indexing,
    gather only work for the first axis. We have to reshape the input data, gather then reshape again
    '''
    reshapedIdx = tf.reshape(idx, [-1]) # [batch_size*num_indices]
    idx_flattened = tile_repeat(tf.shape(x)[0], tf.shape(idx)[1]) * tf.shape(x)[1] + reshapedIdx
    y = tf.gather(tf.reshape(x, [-1,tf.shape(x)[2]]),  # flatten input
                idx_flattened)
    y = tf.reshape(y, [tf.shape(x)[0],tf.shape(idx)[1],tf.shape(x)[2]])
    return y

x = tf.constant([
            [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[3,5,6],[3,5,6]],
            [[7,8,9],[7,8,9],[10,11,12],[10,11,12]],
            [[13,14,15],[13,14,15],[16,17,18],[16,17,18]]
    ])
idx=tf.constant([[0,1],[1,2],[0,3]])

y = gather_along_second_axis(x, idx)
with tf.Session(''):
    print(y.eval())
```